# mod_rewrite has disabled access to folders in root document

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created the following rules that work fine:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$           /search?type=$1&query=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$   /search?type=$1&query=$2&condition=$3 [L]
```

this makes the following conversion

```
/title/limitless   =  /search?type=title&query=limitless
```

but now the problem is I can not access resources from other folders in the root document such as `/images` or `/css`

What have I done wrong?

Comment: For css/js just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: That is the case, i'll call on these files with a forward slash e.g. /images/asdk.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this to ignore rewrite for files/directories:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# skip all rules for real files and directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$         /search?type=$1&query=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search?type=$1&query=$2&condition=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It worked thanks, I'll also give you the answer for the other question